# How to detect intent from Google Play Services Notification

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-notifications, google-play-games

I have an app with google play services(Turn-Base Game), but my main activity has no google play connection.

Google play connection is in seperate activity. I don't want to force my users to connect if they don't want to, and i can't place all the related stuff in my main activity.

My problem is:

1. Someone sends me invite
2. I get notification
3. Notification redirects me to the default google play activity to accept this invite
4. I accept and get redirect to my app's main activity.
5. **How to detect the redirect after accepting invite?**

Because my main activity has no connection to the Google Play, i can't just use

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
   if (connectionHint != null) 
        mMatch = connectionHint.getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_TURN_BASED_MATCH);
}
```

I'm getting different intents on diferent devices, but all of my devices have  **flg=0x14000000**

> Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000
>   cmp=com.virag.game/.Activities.MainActivity }

So for now i use this in my main activity and it works:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent data = getIntent();

        if ( data != null && data.getFlags() == 0x14000000){
           // NetGameActivity is activity with google play connection
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, NetGameActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
}
```

But it feels like a hack and i suppose this flag can be different on some devices out there. So, can it be done with manifest or maybe there is some other way to know that you just got intent from google play services "accept invite menu"?

Comment: `But it feels like a hack..` because it is. I dont understand what you are trying to accomplish here. You say you dont want them to use Google Play Services if they dont want...ok so let them choose to connect then. What you are doing just seem silly

Comment: I want 1) auto-connect and redirect user to the accepted game even if he was signed out before and 2) do not connect if it was just manual log in(maybe he wants to play solo game). But i have no idea how to detect(before connection to GP) that he just accepted some game invite. But yah, probably i should just forget about this and connect in my main activity.

Comment: what is a "manual login" consist of? manual login of GPS?

Comment: "manual login" = user opens my game. i don't want user to see GPS conenction spinner and w8 if he just wants to play solo game.

Comment: so what is wrong with having a button or something to allow them to connect or play a solo game?

Comment: yep i have 2 buttons "solo game", "online game" and user have to select one of them. But I want to detect that user just accepted the game before GPS connection and if so auto-redirect him to the net game.

Comment: @varren, I think everything you said makes absolute sense. Why can't there be a method for sure, in play game services to know if GPS's intent is the one that started our MainActivity? Let me know if you managed to solve it.

Comment: @user3833732 I just gave up and used a flg=0x14000000 flag hack in that app and every other app just had GPS in my main activity. And currently i don't use google play services at all...  prefer my own servers to host the games these days so can't advise

Comment: Well said.. 1 week into this and I kinda realised the same, I should have stuck to my original code with Firebase. Though it was cumbersome to write, I never had to deal with stuff like this!

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to Google Play Services by itself does not require user interaction. Following the [example connecting code](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html#Starting), if the user is already signed in (which I assume would be the case if they are in a turn-based game) then `onConnected()` will be called without the user having to do anything and you can then proceed to get the game.

If they aren't logged in, then `onConnectionFailed()` will be called, however there is no requirement that you immediately call `startResolutionForResult()` to start the log in process - you could just ignore the `onConnectedFailed()` case.

Comment: Ty for your answer, yeah i know that i can do that, but i was hoping that there is a way to know that user just accepted a game in google play services or a way to redirect intent from Google Play Services to my other activity.

Answer (score 2):

As of this moment I can only go 1 up on the Hack by @Varren. I noticed 2 things when our MainActivity is launched by Play Games Services.

> - The **getFlags()** is always 0x14000000.
> - The **getPackage()** is never null, while when we launch the app from    the app Menu or the    Debugging mode it is always null.

So using these 2 pointers, here is what I now check with:

```
Intent i = getIntent();    
int x = i.getFlags();
if(x==0x14000000){Log.d(TAG, "INTENT: flag matches Play!... " + x);}
if(i.getPackage()!=null){Log.d(TAG, "INTENT: package matches Play!... " + getPackage());}

//debug sheet values
//INTENT: flag matches Play!... 335544320
//INTENT: package matches Play!... com.example.MultiPlayerSample
```

At the end of the day, Im still not very confident as I know it still is a hack. I just hope Google Game Play Services could fix this, and give us a flexible but sure solution.

Comment: yeah, i also never found a proper solution, but the problem seems to be not important for most people. only 700 views of this question after 4 years)